# When to use ObserveableCollection<t> instead of List<t>?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to make a `TreeListView` control for my WPF application in order access hierarchical data.
So far I've concluded that I should use `ObserveableCollection<t>` instead of `List<t>` in my non-XAML classes.

But is there a way to just keep using the `List<t>` type for my non-XAML classes?
If yes, then when should I use the `ObserveableCollection<t>`?

Comment: Do you know and understand what an observablecollection is and does?

Comment: it allows to notify when items or properties are changed in the list. So I can update it through the UI. I think.

Comment: @D.Diamond Not quite (but almost!) It notifies the UI whenever its collection is changed. Property changes *do not* propagate unless the held objects implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: The first two comments still were offensive. But I was expecting that.

Comment: @D.Diamond, I apologize if I offended you, I was responding to Rand Random (who was a bit offensive), but could have put more tactfully. It was clear to me that you didn't fully understand what ObservableCollection was (hence your question) and so tried to state that. Again, my apologies for any offfense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` should be used whenever you want changes to the collection (adds and removes) to automatically propagate to a bound control on the UI.

The special thing about `ObservableCollection` is that it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` which `List<T>` does not. So in your "Normal" classes, using it doesn't get you anything. You should use it (almost) all the time in your View Model classes however.

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection has a constructor that takes a List.  You can just construct the ObservableCollection when you get the List in your WPF class.